# Hyperlink control opens a file in a directory and does not open the same file in another directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Dear ASP.NET programmers**

I have a GridView control that contains a hyperlink control in one of it's cells. This hyperlink is supposed to open a file which NavigateUrl property is pointing to. But it does not work properly. In development mode (In visual studio) If I set hyperlink's NavigateUrl property to a file that is on our company's shared server (file://fs/PANTAN/Project/ENG/FIN/Abrisham Oil/ABO289-1976J/PROPOSAL/ABO289-1976Q-REV.0.pdf) it works fine. But if I set NavigateUrl to a file in my local drives (file:///D:/Mr asas/Distributor Manual.pdf) it does not open the file. But this not the whole story. There is something more surprising too. When I deploy the website to our server to be visible for everyone else, the hyperlink control does not function at all. It means that it no longer opens the files on \\fs server. I am setting the file fully qualified path to NavigateUrl property programmatically in code and I know the file path is correct. But I do not know where is the problem source. Please help me with this issue. I am really confused.

Here is the code in which I set NavigateUrl property. I do this in DataBound event of GridView.

```
    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string vendorDocumentNo = ((Label)row.FindControl("vendorDocumentNoLabel")).Text;
            int rev = ConnectToIPMDatabase.GetCorrespondingRev(vendorDocumentNo, Session["selectedTransmittalNo"].ToString());
            ((Label)row.FindControl("revLabel")).Text = rev.ToString();

            int pageNo = ConnectToIPMDatabase.GetDocumentPageNo(vendorDocumentNo, rev);
            if (row.FindControl("pageNoLabel") != null)
            {
                ((Label)row.FindControl("pageNoLabel")).Text = pageNo.ToString();

                string transmittalDocumentLink = ConnectToIPMDatabase.GetDocumentLink(vendorDocumentNo, rev);
                ((HyperLink)row.FindControl("transmittalDocumentLink")).NavigateUrl = transmittalDocumentLink;
            }
            else
            {
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("pageNoTextBox")).Text = pageNo.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share how you are programmatically setting the`NavigateUrl`?

Comment: have you checked all the permissions?

Comment: Dear Richa, code snippet in which NavigateUrl property is set added.

Comment: Permission could also be the problem. But hyperlink control opens the file on client side and in client side (I mean my machine) I have access to \\fs server and all it's sub directories. So it should open the file.